# What's the problem with executing commands in Windows CMD from Python?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, popen

I'm having huge trouble with passing commands to CMD from Python.

First, I open a CMD process:

```
    cmdprocess = subprocess.Popen("cmd",
                                  stdin  = subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Then, I do something, for example:

```
for i in range(500):
     #time.sleep(1)
     command = ("dir > " + os.path.join("C:\\", str(i)) + "\r\n").encode("utf-8")
     print(command)
     cmdprocess.stdin.write(command)
```

So this is supposed to create 500 small text files in a folder. I tested it in Python 3.2 x64 and 3.2 x86 and the result for both is: it counts up to about 250-350 in the Python shell, and then just stops. No error, nothing. There are then the files 1-80 in the specified folder.

Now, I thought that maybe Python is too fast and so had it `sleep(1)` for 1 second between the commands. Now, it counts up to about 200 before the first file appears in the folder! and then stops at about 270.

What happens here and how can I force CMD to execute a command immediately?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using subprocess rather than the standard Python tools for creating files?

Comment: yes, of course: I'm actually using the `mklink` command to create symlinks to files. I just tried to reduce the problem to a smaller, more general command which is easier to write and doesn't need any prerequisites. The problem is identical in both commands.

Answer (score 3):

Are you handling the output in the PIPES? They might be filling. If you fill up the stdout or stderror buffers from the process, it will stop execution.

Comment: No, I'm not ... but if I just run the commands one by one by hand, it doesn't generate any output either. The files just don't appear. The problem with reading from the pipes is that it interrupts the program if I want to read more characters than have been written. I don't get a `''` at the end of file, `read(1)` just blocks ...

Comment: I just tried `peek()` and it works, but I only see that there is absolutely no output ... which hinted me at a possible solution: I might try `flush` on the input stream ...

Comment: Try using `cmdprocess = subprocess.Popen("cmd", stdin  = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)`

Comment: @Bo: I tried that, it now says `cmdprocess.stdin.write(command)
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` before it stops. Any idea what's going wrong there? Does this mean that `stdin` as the implicit first argument to `write` somehow suddenly ceased to exist? I think I'm trying the debugger on this ...

Comment: From what I have it runs all the way through 499 I just get access denied errors before it won't let me write files directly at c:\ here is the full code I have `import subprocess
import os
cmdprocess = subprocess.Popen("cmd", stdin  = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)

for i in range(500):
     command = ("dir > " + os.path.join("C:\\", str(i)) + "\r\n").encode("utf-8")
     print(command)
     cmdprocess.stdin.write(command)`

Comment: @Bo: on which python version are you? ... and i just checked the debugger, the function `cmdprocess.stdin.write` is completely ok, I have no idea what this error message is supposed to mean :( Anyway, lots of thanks for your help!

Comment: Currently running 2.6, I just changed the output path to be a location I can write to and it works for me. I have a folder full of 500 files.

Comment: @Bo: Can you try to do it twice without deleting them in the meantime? Then I *always* get the illegal argument exception.

Comment: I've run it 20 times without removing anything and have gotten zero errors or exceptions. The timestamps on the output files are updating correctly as well.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of time ... or 2.6 is indeed implemented to be more stable. I might just give it a try.

Comment: 20 times with the same cmdprocess object? ok that would definitely disprove my theory

Comment: I didn't do it with the same subprocess object before. But I just did it 30 times with the same subprocess object. Still works.

Comment: I just installed Python 2.6 and tried it there. I tried to create and write to a file on D:\ and it worked. Then I ran exactly the code you posted 29 minutes ago (with D: and without the print parenthesis) and it immediately gives me a `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#72>", line 4, in <module>
    cmdprocess.stdin.write(command)
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` ... No idea how I could find out the reason ...

Comment: Are you on Windows 7? Maybe it comes down to a difference in the operating systems. Would still be strange, then. But not so completely out of the world.

Comment: The machine I was on was Vista.

Comment: @Bo: I tried the `communicate()` method on `cmdprocess` and got an `ValueError: trying to write into closed pipe`. That's probably the reason for the `Errno 22`s. Don't know the reason but at least the error message is somewhat more meaningful. By the way, I finally worked around this program by using a new cmd process for each command with `subprocess.call`. Not elegant and probably much slower, but works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better to use pywin32 package. there are win32pipe and win32process modules.
I also had same issue but I could not resolve it without pywin32-site-package...
So now I am using them... If you need sample code and you're using windows, I will attach it.
if you mean linux... it's same but you need another one like IO select.

Comment: it's quite long... plz.check http://flankton.tistory.com/entry/Python-Command-Process out